# links being inserted into chrome

Tags: malware, malware-removal, anti-malware

I'm seeing malicious links being inserted in web-pages when I am browsing using Google Chrome. It doesn't happen all the time, and it happens even with reputed web-pages. A scan with Malwarebytes and QuickHeal detected nothing. What else should I check?

Comment: Checking for rogue extensions should be the first step.

Comment: Markdown viewer https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-viewer/ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk?hl=en and Application Launcher For Drive (by Google) are the only two extensions.

Comment: Can you provide an example (a copy of source of the page would be nice) where a genuine webpage you had visited had malicous links?  By malicious, do you mean such links where a user is asked or their browser is led to download an executable? Or is such a webpage completely off-topic to the subject matter you were reading on the genuine webpage? For example, you might be reading about "how to use superuser.com" and the malicious link might be about "how to make 100k dollars a week!", thus completely off-topic to the original subject.

Comment: How do you notice these malicious links? Are they opened up on their own without requiring user interaction, or are they embedded in a webpage you are reading/visiting? Are they opened up or embedded on just any webpage you visit or are they limited to certain websites you use/visit?

Comment: I'll try to provide an example/source. The links do not open up on their own. You need to click anywhere in the web-page (not necessarily a link) to go to the link. For instance http://ab-initio.mit.edu/  was directing me to accusationloop.com/w7mvzzrh if I clicked anywhere in the web-page but Quickheal blocked it. I haven't checked what's on accusationloop.com because I don't want to risk infection.

Comment: Doesn't happen when I use Tor. It might be my ISP itself who is playing tricks/or is infected.